# Speech matching api or algorithm

Tags: voice-recognition

Is there any good api or algorithm (free or commercial) for matching two segments of speech audios? There is no need to convert the speech into text. I only want to know whether two segments of audio are speaking the same words. The algorithm should allow for some speed or amplitude variation between the two samples. For example, one sample might be faster and louder than the other sample. And I hope such algorithm should be independent of the languages spoken.

Some people might call this technology voice tag. It's widely used in cars for hands-free calling. You record a voice tag for a person's name in whatever language you like. Later on, you speak the same thing to call that person.

Comment: This algorithm is called [Dynamic Time Warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping). You first extract MFCC features from speech and mean-normalize them to get an equal loudness on all sub bands and after that you can compare two sets of features with DTW. As a result you get a number you can match with a threshold.